# creating sound fx via a software only-any suggestions?

Tags: sfx

Hello everyone,

I will be very thankful for any advice concerning the bellow-

I am willing to create funny/cartoon sound fx (later to be sold as stock sound fx) using a software only, so no external recording is involved.

I am looking for a software that enables such a task, maybe a synth software or or any good alternative that might be helpful.

I will be thankful to know about some good and affordable options.

Thank you in advanced for the help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

I create a lot of Sound Designs and music using nothing but white noise. I take very small sections of the audio (5-200ms) and loop it in a sampler to create a wavetable oscillator. That gives you your basic synthesizer for you to then envelope, filter, modulate etc. Then it's all about your processing chain.. I tend to granulate a lot of audio and use spectral gates, both of which can be achieved using the range of plugs created by Micheal Norris..

http://www.michaelnorris.info/software/soundmagic-spectral.html

(They're free)

For comical sound FX you want to play with Pitch a lot.. I recommend any good sampler (Kontact, Alchemy) Also, experiment with some delay modulation in Logic's Tape Delay or Artificial Audio's Plug 'Quartz'

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the info:-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.superflashbros.net/as3sfxr/ for more 8-bit-sound-like sfx, if it helps... it's free :)

Answer (score -1):

Not going to work.

Most/all of the great cartoon FX are made with inventive physical sound making devices and instruments. See for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=TSf8Er2gV_Q#t=265s for inspiration.

And if you're sampling and repackaging, you'd be violating copyrights.

Comment: The downvoters may explain their "cartoon fx synthesis" tricks, if they wish to.

Comment: The downvote was not because of your knowledge or our lack of, but from your negativity and blunt attitude.

'It would be extremely difficult too' would be a little more encouraging rather than a straight 'NO.' We are all at different skill levels remember. Furthermore, cartoons are evolving everyday. You are being slightly presumptuous with the sound pallet. Go and watch Superjail or Adventure Time and tell me that can't be designed all in Software  

Comment: @Emotekon got any links? I'm quite interested in learning about / hearing this "all in software" approach. 